# C++ program crashes on rotating string by more than it's length

Tags: c++, string, rotation

```
string half_password = password.str();
    if(shift < 0) //left shift
        rotate(half_password.begin(), half_password.begin() + (-1*shift), half_password.end());
    if(shift > 0) //right shift
        rotate(half_password.rbegin(), half_password.rbegin() + shift, half_password.rend());
```

Now, if |shift| > 7 and the length of `half_password` is 8, then my program crashes with a segmentation fault. My question is does the `rotate` function not allow rotation more than the highest index of the string?

I don't have a problem with this, the logic works fine. I would like to know if this is how the `rotate` function works though.

Comment: [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate): "A precondition of this function is that [first, n_first) and [n_first, last) are valid ranges."

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `+ (-1*shift)` can be written shorter and nicer as `- shift`.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Agreed, I just did that for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

> A precondition of this function is that [first, n_first) and [n_first, last) are valid ranges.

When you are beyond the highest index size, or below the lowest index size, these are not valid ranges.

Comment: Couldn't they have programmed it to just loop around again?

Comment: @Torcellite no, because `std::rotate` is not limited to containers that provide random access iterators

Comment: @ninjansen - Could you please elucidate about random access iterators? Sorry, I'm taking up C++ after a long time and I don't think I learnt about iterators back then.

Comment: @Torcellite take a look at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) for an overview over iterators. A random access iterator allows `iterator+n` access.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument to `std::rotate` is an iterator pointing to the element you'd like to be at the beginning of the string, with that said it's fairly easy to understand that giving it an iterator to an element *passed the end/beginning* of your container will result in a crash.

You can circumenvent this issue by using the *modulus operator* `%` to limit the result of adding `shift` to always be in-between `0` and one less than the length of your container.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
```

```
std::string
shift_it (std::string const& src, int shift)
{
  std::string dst = src;

  if (shift < 0)
    std::rotate (dst.begin  (), dst.begin  () + (+shift % dst.size ()), dst.end  ());
  else
    std::rotate (dst.rbegin (), dst.rbegin () + (-shift % dst.size ()), dst.rend ());

  return dst;
}
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cerr << shift_it ("hello", 7) << std::endl;
  std::cerr << shift_it ("hello", 2) << std::endl;

  std::cerr << shift_it ("hello", -7) << std::endl;
  std::cerr << shift_it ("hello", -2) << std::endl;
}
```

<sup>output:</sup>

```
lohel
lohel
llohe
llohe
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is the *middle*, so it should lay between the beginning and end.  Do a `<middle value> % (end() - begin())` to make sure of that.